# Detect when recycler view using GridLayout reach the bottom or count item shown

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am trying to count the number of items displayed by a recyclerview or at least detecting when I am reaching the bottom of it.

Below is my `recyclerView`:

```
binding?.photosGrid?.apply {
    layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(context, 3)
    adapter = flickrPhotosAdapter
    
    addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        override fun onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView: RecyclerView, newState: Int) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState)
        }
        
        override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)
        }
    })
}
```

The Adapter has been defined as below:

```
class FlickrPhotosAdapters(private val viewModel: FlickrViewModel) :
    ListAdapter<PhotoDetails, FlickrPhotosViewHolder>(PHOTO_COMPARATOR) {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): FlickrPhotosViewHolder =
        FlickrPhotosViewHolder.from(parent)

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: FlickrPhotosViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val item = getItem(position)
        item?.let {
            holder.bind(it, viewModel)
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return super.getItemCount()
    }

    companion object {
        private val PHOTO_COMPARATOR = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<PhotoDetails>() {
            override fun areItemsTheSame(
                oldItem: PhotoDetails,
                newItem: PhotoDetails
            ): Boolean =
                oldItem == newItem

            override fun areContentsTheSame(
                oldItem: PhotoDetails,
                newItem: PhotoDetails
            ): Boolean =
                oldItem == newItem
        }
    }
}
```

The overall solution is working but I need to load more data when reaching the end of the recycler view or at least when close to a specific number of items already scrolled by.

I tried 5 solutions using the `addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener()` but nothing is working. I tried :

```
@Override
public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
    
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
    
    if (!isLoading) {
        if (linearLayoutManager != null && linearLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == rowsArrayList.size() - 1) {
            //bottom of list!
            loadMore();
            isLoading = true;
        }
    }
}
```

it's not working at all.

I am running out of idea....

The only thing I want to do is to Load more data (place a rest api call) when close to the bottom or at the bottom.

Thanks

Comment: I'm just assuming that this part `linearLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() == rowsArrayList.size() - 1` never gets true for some reason. Did you try to debug or Log the values of lastVisibleItem to see if that may be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the `FlickrPhotosAdapters` class is the best place to get notified when the scrolling goes toward the end. Because you have all the data you need in the adapter.
Let's say you wanna get notified from the adapter's owner class which probably either be an `Activity` or a `Fragment` class. You could create a notifier interface and implement it in the owner class.

```
interface DemandListener {
    fun onDemand()
}
```

Then in the owner class where you create the adapter you would pass this listener implementation to the adapter as a constructer parameter.

```
class YourAdapterOwnerClass: <Activity or Fragment>, DemandListener {
    
    private val flickrPhotosAdapter: FlickrPhotosAdapters
    
    override fun onDemand() {
        // TODO load more data
    }
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Unit {
        ...
        // In addition to other parameters pass this instance as DemandListener implementer
        flickrPhotosAdapter = FlickrPhotosAdapters(viewModel, this)
        ...
    }
}
```

Finally, declare a demand listener in your adapter and get it by its constructor. When the scrolling toward the end occurs and the list item is being bound in `onBindViewHolder` callback, notify the owner class so that it load more items.

```
class FlickrPhotosAdapters(private val viewModel: FlickrViewModel, private val demandListener: DemandListener) :
ListAdapter<PhotoDetails, FlickrPhotosViewHolder>(PHOTO_COMPARATOR) {
    
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): FlickrPhotosViewHolder =
    FlickrPhotosViewHolder.from(parent)
    
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: FlickrPhotosViewHolder, position: Int) {
        if(position >= getItemCount() - 1) {
            demandListener.onDemand()
        }
        val item = getItem(position)
        item?.let {
            holder.bind(it, viewModel)
        }
    }
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return super.getItemCount()
    }
}
```

You get the idea I guess. The logic is simple however hasn't been tested. You should test it by integrating this logic into your code. Hope it works for you.